# output raw query string with python requests library

Tags: http, python-requests

I am looking for a way to print out the raw http query string when I use the request library in python3. It's for troubleshooting purposes. Anyone has an idea how to do this. I tried to use prepared requests, but it is not what I'm looking for.Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: I am looking to print the raw string of the request I will send, example ...https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=labrador+golden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')

You can use:
response.text or response.content or response.raw